# Transparent background clearing screen java

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, repaint

Im not sure if this problem has come up with anyone else, but Im doing some simple animation things. Im trying to have a transparent background, which has been easy to make with the following code:

```
jf.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

The problem is, whenever the thing im trying to move moves(a shrek picture in my case), it constantly paints and isnt clearing the previous shreks. Ill post all my code down below.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class MoveTest extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

  double velX = 0;
  double velY = 0;
  double moveX = 0;
  double moveY = 0;

  double posX = 1;
  double posY = 1;

  double friction = 1.005;

  BufferedImage image;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    try{                
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("shrek.png"));
    }catch (IOException ex){
      System.out.println("Image Does Not Exist");
    }

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    moveX += velX;
    moveY += velY;

    posX += moveX;
    posY += moveY;
    g.drawImage(image,(int)posX,(int)posY,null);
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    int up = KeyEvent.VK_UP, w = KeyEvent.VK_W;
    int down = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, s = KeyEvent.VK_S;
    int left = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, a = KeyEvent.VK_A;
    int right = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, d = KeyEvent.VK_D;

    if(key == w || key == up)
      velY = -.2;
    if(key == s || key == down)
      velY = .2;
    if(key == a || key == left)
      velX = -.2;
    if(key == d || key == right)
      velX = .2;
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    int up = KeyEvent.VK_UP, w = KeyEvent.VK_W;
    int down = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, s = KeyEvent.VK_S;
    int left = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, a = KeyEvent.VK_A;
    int right = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, d = KeyEvent.VK_D;

    if(key == w || key == up)
      velY = 0;
    if(key == s || key == down)
      velY = 0;
    if(key == a || key == left)
      velX = 0;
    if(key == d || key == right)
      velX = 0;
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MoveTest mt = new MoveTest();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    jf.setTitle("Test one cladss");
    jf.setSize(1440,900);
    jf.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(mt);
    jf.setVisible(true);

    mt.setOpaque(true);
    mt.addKeyListener(mt);
    mt.requestFocusInWindow();

    while(true){
      //jf.removeAll();
      jf.repaint();

      mt.collision();
      mt.friction();
      try {
        Thread.sleep(16);
      } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }

  public void collision(){
    if(posX >= 1440-50|| posX <= 0){
      velX -= (2*velX);
      moveX -= (2*moveX);
    }
    if(posY >= 900-50 || posY <= 0){
      velY -= (2*velY);
      moveY -= (2*moveY);
    }
  }

  public void friction(){
    moveX /= friction;
    moveY /= friction;
  }
}
```

If you anything more information please comment it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated issue: Never read in a file or do any long-running tasks from within a painting method. Why keep re-reading the image file when you only have to and only *should* read it in once. Also you should get all program logic out of your painting method since you can't fully control when or if it will be called. By logic I mean where you set your x and y fields. This should be done within your Swing Timer that you use to drive the animation.

Comment: Also, don't set a JFrame's background but rather set the background of components that it holds such as its contentPane and your drawing JPanel.

Comment: This works fine for me with one small change of adding: jf.setUndecorated(true); before you set your background. I'm not seeing any duplicate sprites

Comment: I added jf.setUndecorated(true); and Im still seeing all the sprites from before.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before. The paintComponent method overridden from a JFrame is different than overriding from all other components. Since you have overriden the JFrame's paint code, it is no longer erasing the background. There are two solution:

1. Add your own JComponent (JPanel would work well) and override it's paint methods instead of the JFrames.

or

2. Clear the canvas yourself as the first thing you do after you call super.paintComponent.

In Addition:

You should not be reading your image every time you paint. Since painting happens soon after repaint is called from any thread, the image could load many many times. If you need to load it once, create a nameless instance block in the class like so:

```
{
  try{                
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("shrek.png"));
  }catch (IOException ex){
    System.out.println("Image Does Not Exist");
  }
}
```

If you are only ever going to have one copy, make it a static block:

```
static {
   <load image here>
}
```

If you want to reload the image every frame because it changes you need to find a way not to do that. Instead any image animation should happen by editing the BufferImage object in java or loading a sprite-map.